# Java Swing JLabel setText doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, jnlp

I want to update JLabel with setText() method, but when I update it, text shows like this: [image: Example is here]

Comment: Er, what layout manager are you using? Could you show us the code for your GUI?

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by not having a layout manager and not setting the location of the labels. By not setting any location for the labels they have defaulted 0 (x) and 0 (y), there for they are on top of one another. To set the location of a label do `label.setlocation(x, y);` and to set a layout manager do `frame.setLayout(Type layout manager here);`